# Alternate for Array Sum Formula

Tags: arrays, excel

Table copied as Text

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6
A   AA  AAA 100 95  92
A   AA  AAA 85  83  81
A   AA  BBB 200 199 160
A   BB  AAA 65  55  49
B   AA  AAA 89  88  83
B   AA  BBB 150 149 145
B   BB  AAA 140 135 
B   BB  BBB 190 185 
B   AA  AAA 510     


    AA              
        AAA BBB     
    A   173 160     
    B   593 145
```

and some more explanation

Basically i want the sum of "Column 6" for the given criteria but the data in Column 6 can only be entered after some delay w.r.t. Column 1, Column 2, Column 3 & Column 4.

Till Column 6 data is entered, i want excel to use the number available in Column 5 which is also entered after some delay w.r.t. Column 1, Column 2, Column 3 & Column 4 but before Column 6.

And till Column 5 data is entered, i want excel to use the number available in Column 4.

Now I am familiar with two SUM/IF arrangements as included below in post.

First one is array sum/if arrangement which is convenient to write but results in terribly long calculation time with 1.5 seconds for just one column and I have over 100 columns in one sheet and about 9 sheets.

Second one is using SUMIFS which requires extensive time to write but relatively better calculation time of 0.5 seconds for column but is still quite high.

Now I need to do away with the array arrangement but doing so will take quite some time and I want to know if there is any better/other arrangement.

Just let me know other arrangement which can get the required result and I will check the arrangement for calculation timing. If the other arrangement is also convenient to write than that is a plus.

This is my table:

[image]

And I want to add the right most columns which are not empty i.e. have a number in it, but with the criteria for the first three columns in cell `D15`.

I only found option to add image. Please let me know how to upload excel file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6mIz.jpg)

Can somebody please suggest an alternate to this array formula so it can calculate way faster

```
{=SUM(
IF(
($B$2:$B$10=$C15)*
($C$2:$C$10=$C$13)*
($D$2:$D$10=D$14)>0,
IF(
$G$2:$G$10<>"",
$G$2:$G$10,
IF(
$F$2:$F$10<>"",
$F$2:$F$10,
$E$2:$E$10))))}
```

I have tried below which reduces the calculation time to 1/3 but it is too much typing for the large data I am dealing with

```
=SUMIFS(
$G$2:$G$10,
$B$2:$B$10,$C15,
$C$2:$C$10,$C$13,
$D$2:$D$10,H$14,
$G$2:$G$10,"<>"&"")
+SUMIFS(
$F$2:$F$10,
$B$2:$B$10,$C15,
$C$2:$C$10,$C$13,
$D$2:$D$10,H$14,
$G$2:$G$10,"="&"",
$F$2:$F$10,"<>"&"")
+SUMIFS(
$E$2:$E$10,
$B$2:$B$10,$C15,
$C$2:$C$10,$C$13,
$D$2:$D$10,H$14,
$G$2:$G$10,"="&"",
$F$2:$F$10,"="&"")
```

Comment: Might be easier if you post some sample data and explain what the formula does.

Comment: Found option to add image. Please check again.

Comment: @tabbymulla To make it easier for us to help you, when posting sample data please post as plan text, so we can copy/paste it.  If an image adds context, then add that too.

Comment: An image of the sample data isn't useable, as it can't be copied and pasted to use for testing. You can't find a link to upload an Excel file because that's not acceptable either; you can't expect us to download a file from an unknown person to our machines. You've also asked us to improve code without explaining the problem you're trying to solve or what the formula is supposed to do. .

Comment: @KenWhite IMO an image of sample data is fine, as long as it illustrates the problem and the expected result (which I agree that this still doesn't).

Comment: @jsheeran: IMO, that's incorrect, for the reasons I already explained. If we want to test a possible solution, we can't copy sample data from an image of an Excel workbook. Also, see [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of reasons that images should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: I have managed to copy paste the table included in the image as text and also included detailed explanation for better understanding. Please go through and share your ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're OK with using a helper column (which you should be), you can use this formula in a helper cell and drag down. (In my example at bottom, this formula is in cell `H2` and drag down.)

```
= INDEX(E2:G2,MATCH(-1E+300,E2:G2,-1))
```

This gets all of the data in either column 4 5 or 6 all into one column.

Then you can use a simpler `SUMIFS` formula in cell `D15`:

```
= SUMIFS($H$2:$H$10,         // Sum range (helper column)
         $B$2:$B$10,$C15,    // Criteria 1 (A or B)
         $C$2:$C$10,$C$13,   // Criteria 2 (AA or BB)
         $D$2:$D$10,D$14)    // Criteria 3 (AAA or BBB)
```

See below, working example:

[image]

---

**DISCLAIMER**

This answer will simplify your formulas, but I'm not sure if this will help with the performance problems you are experiencing. `SUMIFS` in itself I don't see being likely the cause of long calculation times. Probably you are experiencing long calculation times because other parts of your spreadsheet are using inefficient formulas and/or formulas involving volatile cells, but that is just a guess because I have no idea what the rest of your spreadsheet looks like.

Comment: Thanks. The calculation time for SUMIFS with helper column arrangement (a little adjustment in helper formula since in my actual data, data columns are not adjacent) was average 0.14 seconds (0.12 seconds for SUMIFS formula column and 0.02 seconds for Helper column) in comparison to average 1.5 seconds for the array sum/if formula and average 0.5 seconds for SUMIFS formula I mentioned in my original post for the same column's calculation.

Comment: @tabbymulla If this answer works for you, please mark it as correct by placing a checkmark next to it.