# Auto expansion of a formula containing intermediate formulas in preceding cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following scenario,

```
A2 is a text cell, 
B2 contains "=FIND("data",A2)", 
C2 contains "=FIND(" ",A2,B2)+1",
D2 contains "=FIND(" ",A2,C2)",
E2 contains "=D2-C2",
G2 contains "=MID(A2,C2,E2)"
```

Is there a way for the formula in G2 `=MID(A2,C2,E2)` to auto evaluate to the formula below

```
=MID(A2, FIND(" ",A2,FIND("data",A2))+1, FIND(" ",A2,(FIND(" ", A2,FIND("data",A2))+1)) - (FIND(" ",A2,FIND("data",A2))+1))
```

without going thru the hairy process of manually copying and substituting preceding formulas from B2 thru E2 in G2?

**Additional info**: Here columns B to E contains intermediate formulas to build the final formula in column G to extract the word immediately after the word `data` in the text column A. The goal is to have the final formula in column G to refer to only column A instead of so many preceding columns B to E

Many thanks for your help in advance.

[image: Example screen shot]

Comment: Not without vba.  But once you have it done in the first cell all you need to do is drag the formula down and it will change the references.

Comment: @ScottCraner, sorry not following, can you elaborate your approach please?

Comment: How about share some sample sentences and tell us which word or words you are trying to extract? Maybe there is a better approach that you are not aware of.

Comment: @TerryW, I updated my question details and uploaded a new screen shot to show example sentences. I'd be delighted to learn a better approach I am ignorance about. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try one of the following:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,FIND("data",A2),LEN(A2))," ",REPT(" ",100),2),6,100))
```

> The logic is to use **MID** function to find the part of the string starting `data`, and then use **SUBSTITUTE** to replace the second space (which is the space after the target word) in the string with 100 spaces (using **REPT** function) so the string would become something like `data targetword (100 spaces) nextword`. Then use **TRIM+MID** to find the second word in the substituted string.

or

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[text()='data']/following-sibling::*[1]")
```

> For the logic behind this formula you may give a read to this article: [Extract Words with FILTERXML](https://chandoo.org/wp/extract-words-with-filterxml/).

Please note if the word your are trying to extract has a symbol such as `,` or`?` next to them, the symbol will also be extracted. Eg. in the following sentence: `Are you data ok?`, the above formulas will return `ok?` instead of `ok`.

One way to fix it is to extract all the words (with symbols) first, and then use **SUBSTITUTE** function to replace all symbols with blank `""` for instance.

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Comment: Wow! You are a super user no doubt. I'm at elementary level, would you explain the substitute and rept parts in the first formula? 
I can see second formula is for parsing XML text, it is a little too advanced for me, what do you suggest me to read to understand the parts in this formula? Thanks!

Comment: I learned all the tricks in this community :) Do you know you can press the **F9** key on your key board to debug a formula? For instance if you highlight `REPT(" ",100)` in the first formula in your formula bar and press **F9**, you will see what the formula will return which should be a long string containing 100 spaces. I will update my answer with some explanations, and you can use **F9** to break the formula down to understand the logic behind.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer the solution of using the helper cells as opposed to having one gigantic nested formula. Here it doesn't seem to make much of a difference, but helper cells can sometimes drastically improve efficiency of formulas. Also using helper cells allows formulas to be easier to understand (because you can see the results of intermediate steps). If I were you, I'd keep the helper cells and just hide those columns.

But anyway, answering your question, there is a bit of room for improvement. See below. Notice you find "data " (with a space at the end) then add 5 immediately. This skips one step.

[image]

One comment: You might want to add some extra checking in the event that the target word is the last word in the string. If it is the last word, then it won't find a space after it (which would result in error).

E.g. change this:

```
= FIND(" ",A2,B2)
```

to this:

```
= IFERROR(FIND(" ",A2,B2),LEN(A2))
```

Comment: Thanks! yes, I agree helper cells are easier to understand than one gigantic cell, especially for ordinary users.

Comment: @ngBeginner Not only easier to understand, also speeds up calculation times because the result is stored. For example with helper cells `FIND("data",...)` is only calculated _once_ but if you use a nested formula, the same formula is calculated _multiple times_ (because it appears in the formula multiple times). You are sacrificing space in your spreadsheet for clarity and calculation times. But this isn't really much of a sacrifice since Excel allows you to hide cells. Anyway, please mark one of these answers as correct by placing a checkmark next to it.

Comment: @ngBeginner FYI, [here is a recent SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57712741/alternate-for-array-sum-formula/57732092#comment101907886_57732092) where the asker was experiencing slow calculation times. The answer added a helper column, which sped up the calculation times tenfold according to the asker.